# How can I restart the process that updates the desktop background?

Tags: lubuntu, gui, panel

I am not sure what I did, but something's caused the background of my desktop GUI (Lubuntu 22.04.3LTS, LXQt) to no longer refresh when a window closes or when I switch to a different virtual background.  Things are still running, but if I close a window, it appears to still be open (it's not, it's just a frozen still artifact on the backdrop).  It means that it's getting very hard to tell what's the active, usable windows and what are just images.

I'm running a process that won't complete for a few days (a backup), so before trying to restart the computer I'd love to just restart whatever's running the window handling and background images and such.  Is there a way to do that without logging out and thus stopping the backup that I'm not wanting to interrupt?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm using Lubuntu *noble*, and a `ps -elf |grep pcmanfm-qt` shows `/usr/bin/pcmanfm-qt --desktop --profile=lxqt` as running, which is what is handling much of the desktop running on my system (including background image.wallpaper).  Do you see it running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using Lubuntu *noble*, thus using LXQt 1.4 which will be the same version as you IF you're using [Lubuntu backports](https://lubuntu.me/jammy-backports-22-04-3-lxqt-1-4/), but this should work on any *supported* release of Lubuntu.

A quick view of what is running using `ps -elf |grep pcmanfm-qt` showed the following, which is what handles my desktop

`/usr/bin/pcmanfm-qt --desktop --profile=lxqt`

If I kill that process, which I can do with a `killall pcmanfm-qt`, my screen backgrounds will all go black (*where I have no windows anyway*).. as I just killed what caused my wallpaper to display.

To restart that, I can use

`pcmanfm-qt --desktop --profile=lxqt &`

which causes the black borders of my current screen to return to showing a picture (*instead of black*), no change on two screens where windows completely hide background, and full wallpaper viewable on one display that has no windows.

**This detail may help you IF you're using a Lubuntu/LXQt session.**

You describe the windows not disappearing on closure, which does not happen on this box for my current LXQt session (*when I killed pcmanfm-qt's handling of my screen wallpaper/background*), thus this answer maybe missing your actual problem.

What you describe I see most if using an *openbox* session and not an *lxqt* session, as `pcmanfm-qt` is **not** handling the desktop in that case, but you do mention LXQt in your question (Lubuntu installs with LXQt (using `openbox` as WM) AND provides other sessions to including a a pure *Openbox*).

I've only tested this answer when using the Lubuntu/LXQt session, not an *openbox* only session (*also available for Lubuntu users*).

Comment: I didn't switch away from my *primary* box with runs the *development* release (ie. *noble* currently) to test this on another box ... but I see little need. Besides what the OP describes reminds me of an *openbox* session, rather than an LXQt session  (a standard Lubuntu install offers a *Lubuntu* session which has all our configs, a LXQt session (purer upstream LXQt experience), OR an *openbox* session (no desktop, just the `openbox` WM).  The `openbox` session does vary a little between releases though, so specific details as to what was installed (any backports etc) need to be known.

Comment: That worked magic.  I wasn't able to find the running process so I just used the latter command to start up pcmanfm-qt again, and it's back to normal.  

Now I'm curious, I'm remembering the last thing I did before it crashed was try to use the 22.04.3LTS wallpaper, that cool jellyfish...Is there some problem with that image that caused pcmanfm-qt to crash??

Comment: I doubt it (*at least I only recall issues with much older versions (lxqt) & Lubuntu releases; eg. 20.04*).. but if there was a crash I'd expect to see clues in system logs, even a crash file in `/var/crash/` that would match the time/date where it closed/wallpaper disappeared. Either way I'd not worry (*assume it closed as a result of an action you did; maybe your process is using loads of RAM & systemd-oomd killed processes to create available RAM - you'll find evidence of that in system logs too! and whatever is using all the RAM maybe more of a worry, but its not a LXQt/pcmanfm-qt issue*)

Comment: If your "*process that won't complete for a few days*" is using tons of RAM, then systemd-oomd is something I'd check for involvement as already mentioned. I know I've written about it many times on this site, but I don't have easy links sorry; thus if you'd like to read more I'll provide a link to a question https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/get-warning-on-low-memory-to-avoid-freezing/3233 which includes a link to Ubuntu-MATE's discourse where I've written some more..... the Ubuntu-MATE link contains journal messages as example (message vary on kernel being used; GA=5.15, HWE=6.2, edge=6.5)

Comment: If you've not already increased *swap* size post-install (ie. still using no, or 512MB of swap), I'd for sure increase that asap....  Links in my reply on https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/get-warning-on-low-memory-to-avoid-freezing/3233/2

Comment: Thank you @guiverc, I don't think I've done any post-install increasing of swap, but I'm in 22.04 now...does that systemd-oomd thing you mention prevent problems?  Until now I hadn't had any issues.  I did find somewhere a nice step through you wrote about increasing swap post install, I believe it was for 22.04.  So maybe I'll do that.  I'm on a 40GB Ram system, so...it's pretty zippy normally.  But still, swap helps!

Comment: You have more RAM than any box I use (*outside of servers where I'm not using a desktop*) so I have no useful experience of LXQt on a machine with 40GB RAM, and FYI the https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/how-to-create-a-swapfile-in-lubuntu-20-04-later/1959 page I just amended (it was https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/how-to-create-a-swapfile-in-lubuntu-20-04-20-10/1959 mentioning 20.04 & 20.10 relating to when it was created.. the 1959 in URL/link will mean correct/latest page is still shown) as that applies to all current releases (*still applies so far in noble or 24.04 too, but that may change*)

Comment: The systemd OOMd process will constantly monitor the system, and if it a *low ram* situation is detected, it'll create more RAM by killing current processes.. my link contained a link to [here on Ubuntu-MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/what-all-is-inbound-with-22-04/25130/3) where I talked about it regularly killing my `chromium` and `firefox` browsers.. Outside of systemd journal (system logs) no detail is given except if you notice the process being killed. I have no idea if that's your issue, or it was a crash (`/var/crash` I suggested; `dmesg`, `journalctl` etc) giving where I'd look